# I try to config url in yii 2 advanced, but I got an error

Tags: php, server, yii2

In my config frontend/main.php I have this config.

```
 'rules' => [
            'contact' => 'site/contact',
            'category-product' => 'category-product/index',
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        ],
```

and url is `['label' => 'Products', 'url' => ['/category-product']]`,

I got an internal server error.

Comment: '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
10
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
11
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',

Comment: what are you trying here? also add more details of error , you can enable detailed error display by adding debug to **web/index.php** file as below   

`defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');`